# Using onclick to navigate pages in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I have an HTML element (that was generated using javascript) that has an onclick property set to run a function, like so:

```
<tr onclick="navtoprod()">
 <td>item1</td>
 <td>item2</td>
 <td>item3</td>
</tr>
```

And I have a function:

```
function navtoprod() {
  document.window.location = 'http://www.enviroptics.com/';
}
```

When I click on tr it returns that navtoprod is undefined.

Is my problem strictly syntax related? I've tried document.location and window.location separately and nothing worked. Heres my fiddle that I'm working on in case my problem is not as simple as I hope it is. https://jsfiddle.net/msirkin/kpkn13w7/

EDIT: I cant use a jquery solution

Comment: Change row.setAttribute('onclick', 'navtoprod()'); to row.setAttribute('onclick', navtoprod);

Comment: @artamonovdev I tried that and the error goes away but the page doesn't navigate to where it's supposed to

Comment: Check code out jsfiddle, he don't work again?

Comment: @artamonovdev I've updated the fiddle so you can try it with the changes that you recommened. https://jsfiddle.net/msirkin/kpkn13w7/1/   

In theory it should navigate to a different page when i click on any of my rows, but it doesnt

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/artamonovdev/duw5nyqe/3/ - work good, check code outside jsfiddle